# Server to Server HTTP GET/POST gets an ERROR 400 - Same URL when hit on the browser is processed as expected

Tags: php, mysql, http

We have been trying to integrate this callback method which is basically a HTTP GET / POST from our partner's server to ours. The Callback URL looks like this -

```
http://www.yourserver.com/callback.php?tid=[=tid=]&uid=[=order_id=]&timestamp=[=timestamp=]&country=[=country=]&ip=[=ip=]&useragent=[=useragent=]&sid=[=subid=]&payout=[=payout=]&currency=[=currency=]&udid=[=iphone_udid=]&campaign_id=[=campaign_id=]
```

Whenever a transaction happens our partner's servers which are outside of the realm that we are in is posted to our servers where we have a callback.php service that processes the required and receives the data from the post and writes to a mysql database.

We are noticing that hitting the URL above on a browser gets the data as expected and writes it into the database. But when the Server to Server HTTP call happens the posting server receives a ERROR 400.

This callback method is executed without authentication through http and not https just to keep things simple for now.

callback.php code that we are using is below.

```
<?php
include "DBConnection.inc";
require("logging.php");

// Fetch data from callback url
$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$tid = $_REQUEST['tid'];
$sid = $_REQUEST['sid'];    
$timestamp = $_REQUEST['timestamp'];
$country = $_REQUEST['country'];
$ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
$useragent = $_REQUEST['useragent'];    
$payout = $_REQUEST['payout'];
$currency = $_REQUEST['currency'];
$udid = $_REQUEST['udid'];
$campaign_id = $_REQUEST['campaign_id'];    

// Initialize the local variables
$errorLoggingPath = "callback-url.log";

// Insert data into database
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tb_callback_url VALUES ('$uid', '$tid', '$sid', '$timestamp', '$country', '$ip', '$useragent', '$payout', '$currency', '$udid', '$campaign_id')";
mysql_query($insertQuery);

if( mysql_errno() <> 0 )
{
    LogError("INSERT failed in tb_callback_url: " . mysql_error(), __FILE__, __LINE__ , $errorLoggingPath);
}

mysql_close();?>
```

Is there anything in particular we should look into in terms of web server settings or the callback.php code?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How is the server to server call being made ? The one that throws out the 400. Can you show me the code for that please ?

Comment: We do not have access to that code @AshrayBaruah. Is there anything in particular that we should be interested in that code?

Comment: Check that you're building a properly-encoded URL - in particular things like the user-agent field could contain URL metachars that browsers are politely fixing for you, but your callback code isn't.